# Xerox Phaser 3020 won't print on the first try

Tags: macos, printer

I have a Xerox Phaser 3020 wifi printer.

It works without a problem except that it won’t print in the first try but it will print in the second try. Can anyone guess why this is happenning.

I’m using a MacBook Air.

Comment: On the 2nd try, does it print both copies, or only 1?

Comment: It prints only one.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the printer and reinstalling? Does it do the same if you connect it via USB?

Comment: It prints fine via USB. I tried to update the driver but it didn't help. For some reason I could't find the installer for Mac. There are only the drivers. Where do I find the installer?

Comment: On a Mac, you don't normally need to download drivers, you just add the printer and let the Mac do the rest. You never need an installer. The driver on the Xerox website is a .dmg file; just double-click it and let it do its thing. And, as it prints fine via USB, the drivers appear fine anyway.